# What's the difference between Kaguya's 'O kawaii koto' and Miyuki (Shirogane)'s 'O kawaii yatsu-me'?

Tags: phrases, manga, anime

From [Kaguya-sama: Love Is War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War):

As you know (Gasai) from [memes](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/o-kawaii-koto), Kaguya often says (either actually or in Miyuki's imagination) 'お可愛いこと' (o kawaii koto). You can even see like a compilation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90ao8I1djTE).

[image]

Miyuki seems to say something similar (either actually or in Kaguya's imagination) 'お可愛い奴め' (O kawaii yatsu-me ?)

From the anime S01E11 (eg [here](https://youtu.be/dmAqNh2qApE?t=50))

[image]

or from the manga [Chapter 42](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_42)

[image]

Questions:

1. What's the exact rōmaji here? O kawaii yatsu-me? O kawaii yatsume? O kawaii yatsuume?
2. What's the difference? I'm guessing still 'practically they are used synonymously' again like the [2 true love's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66584/difference-between-the-2-true-love-that-kaguya-says)...but then theoretically though...?

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty simple, cursory answer, but:

こと here is a sentence-ending particle stereotypically associated with, I'd say, elegant ladies/お嬢さん.　Second to last entry, first definition [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8/), essentially it expresses strong feelings.

Meanwhile やつめ is an actual noun. やつ is a not-so-polite way of saying 'a person' and め is a suffix adding an additional insulting nuance, though in this case it doesn't seem to be *too* rough? It's something like 'cute little devil', 'cute little fucker' depending on how roughly the character talks.

The hyphens aren't actually part of Romaji so you can use them or leave them as you like, but 'yatsuume' would be pronounced differently and is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Angelos. Perhaps I'll notice some such こと when I watch the new Higurashi(/Umineko). 1 - Actually I was thinking about the ojou-san (ojou-sama in this case because the show is called Kaguya-sama?). What I thought was Miyuki was doing like the male version. So apparently, not really, Miyuki's just doing like 'cute little devil' ? 2 - Wait... やつ...ahhhh (now with the hiragana I think I recognise this word) is it like koitsu / aitsu?